# Msbuild copy command failed if path contains double byte characters

Tags: msbuild, wix

I am using WIX project to create an MSI file.

Following statements are added in WIXPROJ file to copy MSI file.

copy /y "!(TargetPath)" "$(MSIPath)\"

$(MSIPath) contains the path which is double byte characters.
Ex: F:\Temp\つも追加さ\
error MSB3073: The command "copy /y "E:\BuildMSI\bin\Debug\en-Us\xxx.msi" "F:\Temp\つも追加さ\"" exited with code 1.

Note: Same is working fine Japanese OS. This issue occurs in English OS.

Please help me how to resolve this issue.

Thanks in advance.

Regards,
Dileep

Comment: Try, in your .wixproj, using the MSBuild [Copy Task](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3e54c37h(v=vs.100).aspx) instead of batch commands. Maybe put it in an [AfterBuild](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171462(v=vs.100).aspx) target.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have used the 'AfterBuild' command instead of 'PostBuildEvent'.

```
<Target Name="AfterBuild">          
  <Copy SourceFiles="$(TargetPath)" DestinationFolder="$(MSIPath)" /> 
</Target>
```

Issue was solved using the above statements in Wixproject file.

Comment: Sometimes for developers that aren't familiar with MSBuild I put a batch remark in the Post Build Event box like: `@rem Open this .wixproj as XML to see AfterBuild tasks`